# laravel select model value without column name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i want to select the data from modal then only get the value and set the value to datatables. since the columns is dynamic i cant have the column name on the result

i have try

```
public function test()
    {
        return Model::pluck('id','name');
    }
```

but the result is like this

```
{ 
    1 : "name 1", 
    2 : "name 2" 
}
```

i need the result to be

```
[
    { 1, "name 1" },
    { 2, "name 2" }
]
```

using Model::all(['id', 'name']);

```
[
    { "id" : "1" , "name" : "name 1" },
    { "id" : "2" , "name" : "name 2" }
]
```

how to remove the "id" and "name"?

Comment: `{ 1, "name 1" }` is not a valid JSON

Comment: Did you get this solved? or tried below answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have object values without keys. So closest thing you can do is return them as arrays.

```php
$all = Model::all(['id', 'name'])->map(function($model) {
    return [model->id, model->name];
})->toArray();
```

this will result:

```php
[
    0 => [
        0 => 1,
        1 => 'name 1'
    ],
    1 => [
        0 => 2,
        1 => 'name 2'
    ]
]
```

note that these `0 =>` are not keys, those are array indices. So you can ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function test()
{
    return Model::pluck('id','name');
}
```

if you want to get `id` and `name` as key and value, use `pluck`, if you want to retrieve only those two columns, better use `only`.

```
public function test()
 {
    return Model::only('id','name');
 }
```